# Mongodb toArray() performance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

I have a collection 'matches' with 727000 documents inside. It has 6 fields inside, no arrays just simple integers and object Ids. I am doing query to collection as follows:

```
matches.find({
  $or: [{
      homeTeamId: getObjectId(teamId)
    }, {
      awayTeamId: getObjectId(teamId)
    }
  ],
  season: season,
  seasonDate: {
    '$gt': dayMin,
    '$lt': dayMax
  }
}).sort({
  seasonDate: 1
}).toArray(function (e, res) {
  callback(res);
});
```

Results returning only around 7-8 documents. 
The query takes about ~100ms, which i think is quite reasonable, but the main problem is, when i call method toArray(), it adds about ~600ms!!
I am running server on my laptop, Intel Core I5, 6GB RAM but i can't believe it adds 600ms for 7-8 documents.
Tried using mongodb-native driver, now switched to mongoskin, and stil getting the same slow results.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: What does `callback()` do?

Comment: It returns data from function. I have wrapped this query inside function exports.getPrevNextMatches = function(teamId, callback){} . But when i do the same without toArray() method, to return a cursor of results, it takes as mentioned ~100 ms. toArray() method adds ~600ms

Comment: did you try `forEach` on the `find` result instead of `toArray`? I doubt it will help, but it's an easy thing to try. Also, what's `explain` give you for that query?

Answer (score 3):

toArray() method iterate throw all cursor element and load them on memory, it is a highly cost operation. Maybe you can add index to improve your query performance, and/or avoid toArray iterating yourself throw the Cursor.

Regards,
Moacy